# Custom Button Using Search Functionality

Tags: error-messages, code, required-field

I have a project I'm stumped on. I'm adding a detail page button that uses the search functionality to create a Find Duplicates Button on Contacts. Below is the code I'm using. I'm getting the following syntax error message: "The Name field is required". However, I can't make the Name field not required (see screenshot below code).

Interestingly, another admin at another company with a separate SFDC instance used my code exactly and hasn't had an issue or error message. Mind helping me troubleshoot? Any advice greatly appreciated. -Best, Brooks

```
/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?searchType=2&str=
{!IF(  ISNULL(Contact.Phone) ,'',Contact.Phone &' or ' )}
{!IF(  ISNULL(Contact.MobilePhone) ,'',Contact.MobilePhone &' or ' )}
{!Contact.FirstName}+{!Contact.LastName}
+or+{!Contact.Email}
```

[image: Not Able to Change Name Field From Required to Read-Only]

Comment: Are you overriding the save button with this button? That might cause the 'Name field required' error. If it's just a separate button, this error should never occur..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, not overriding the save button. To complicate things further, I created another free trial instance of SFDC and used the code without any error so I'm clueless and give up.

Comment: OK, that makes sense indeed. Maybe better to close the question then, so future readers don't spend their time on it unnecessarily :-)